# Glossary package - acronyms with numbers not accepted

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm having some trouble with acronyms such as I2C, where there is a number inside.
My code is like the following:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossary}
\makeglossary
\newacronym{I2C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}{}

\begin{document}
\I2C
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that commands names can't containing numbers. However, the `glossary` package is obsolete and has been replaced by `glossaries`.

Comment: [Welcome to TX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! If you indent your code by four spaces, it will show up as code, as it can be seen now in your question. Moreover, we don't write "Thank you"'s here.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossary}
\makeglossary
\newacronym[IIC]{I2C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}{}

\begin{document}
\IIC
\end{document}
```

However since `glossary` is obsolete, it's better to use the replacement `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossary
\newacronym{I2C}{I2C}{Inter-Integrated Circuit}

\begin{document}
\gls{I2C}
\end{document}
```